# Python list difference with number of ocurrences

Tags: python, list, comparison

Is there a list subtraction / list diff function built in with python?
I know how to write such a function, so no need to explain that. But since it's a common thing to do, I would like to know if there is already such a function built in.

I have two sorted lists, each may contain multiple copies of identical elements.

I want to know what is the difference between the lists, taking into account the number of occurrences (set difference won't suffice)

For example:

```
l1 = [1,1,2,3,5,6]
l2 = [1,2,8,9]

diff (l1, l2) 
[1,3,5,6]

diff (l2,l1)
[8,9]
```

Comment: The traditional way to solve this problem is to use sets instead. Sets have various operations for difference, union, et c.  Of course, constructing sets are expensive, so if your lists are large or if you cannot use sets "from the beginning" this will not solve your problem.

Comment: @Bittrance -- sets, which are collections of *distinct* items, won't handle duplicate items correctly, e.g. in the case of `l1` above with two `1`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can just use the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) class.

---

**Example:**

```
l1 = [1,1,2,3,5,6]
l2 = [1,2,8,9]
from collections import Counter

print Counter(l1) - Counter(l2)
print Counter(l2) - Counter(l1)
```

**Result:**

> Counter({1: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
>   Counter({8: 1, 9: 1})

---

**Edit:**

To get a list back from the `Counter` object, you can use this code:

```
from itertools import chain
r = Counter(l2) - Counter(l1)
list(chain(*[p*[k] for k,p in r.items()]))
```

I just create a list of lists out of the dictionary-like `Counter`, then use `list(chain(* ... ))` to flatten this into a single list.

Comment: how to get the answer back as a list?

Comment: yes, but his solution is not very readable. also- there should be a counter -> list method?

Comment: @InbarRose `Counter` was added python 2.7

Comment: @InbarRose: I simplified my solution a little bit

Comment: to convert `Counter` to a list: `list(r.elements())`

Answer (score 2):

I think that the solution from `BigYellowCactus` is perfect.
I just wanted to add how one could expand `Counter` to a list back:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a=[1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,2,2]
>>> b=[1,1,1,2,3]
>>> list(chain(*[[k]*v for (k,v) in (Counter(a)-Counter(b)).items()]))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
```

Comment: You can have it simpler by using `p*[k] for k,p` instead of `repeat(k, v) for (k,v)`, otherwise: nice addition! +1

Answer (score 1):

use set

```
l1 = [1,1,2,3,5,6]
l2 = [1,2,8,9]

def  diff (list1, list2) :
    return list(set(list1).difference(set(list2)))

print diff(l1,l2)

>>> 
[3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: taking into account the number of occurrences

Comment: +1 because it's a very nice way to go if the number of occurences doesn't matter

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently using this:

```
def listdiff (l1, l2):
    for x in l1:
        if x in l2:
            l1.remove(x)
            l2.remove(x)
    return l1
```

Comment: This will give false results because you're modifying the list you're iterating over.

Comment: Also, your function will modify the lists in the caller's scope which a) is not a good idea, especially if b) you're returning the result again (because that implies you're not modifying the original list).